# Can I sign an assembly for which I do not have source code?

Tags: .net, assemblies

I have received an assembly from a third party. I need to add it to the GAC, but it does not have a strong name. Is there any way for me to sign the assembly using my own key so that it will be strong named?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. You can use [ILDASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language#Generation) to disassemble the assembly into [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code, and use [ILAsm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILAsm) to reassemble that CIL code and sign it with your own key.

I've done this with various third-party assemblies, and it works just fine.

Comment: Net-fu link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. However,  the solution is not straightforward. You will find instructions on signing third-party assemblies in *[.NET-fu: Signing an Unsigned Assembly (Without Delay Signing)](http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/)*.