# How to use assembly without Strong Name in SSIS

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis

I want to use a assembly in a SSIS task. However, it is unsigned and third-party. Therefore, I can't GAC it. What workarounds are available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an answer.  Disassmble, then re-assemble and sign the assembly with your key.  Prolly wanna check with your 3rd party to see if this kind of surgery is allowed by the license.

The details: [Can I sign an assembly for which I do not have source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899856/can-i-sign-an-assembly-for-which-i-do-not-have-source-code)

Comment: Ran into this today and had to rethink my strategy for an integration application I'm working on. Really sucks that this is **required** by SQL Server / SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

None to my knowledge.  We ran into this issue recently and wound up disassembling (ildasm), signing and reassembling (ilasm).  We also tried to work with the vendor to get them to sign their assembly, but they would not.  We would up dropping that vendor and using another that was more friendly to a realistic deployment scenario.  I hope you find a better way. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround is to copy it to home directories of all the application that will design and run this package.

Usually, it is enough to copy to
1) location of VS IDE:

```
Visual Studio\Common7\IDE\Private Assemblies\
```

2) location of dtexec, dtsdebughost, etc:

```
Microsoft SQL Server\Dts\Binn\
```

The application will be able to load the assembly from its home directory.